# Order of linear algebra operations in Julia

Tags: julia

If I have a command `y = A*B*x` where `A` & `B` are large matrices and `x` & `y` are vectors, will Julia preform `y = ((A*B)*x)` or `y = (A*(B*x))`?

The second option should be the best as it only has to allocate an extra vector rather than a large matrix.

Comment: If this is a general problem for you, then perhaps this package: https://github.com/AustinPrivett/MatrixChainMultiply.jl can be of help. Supposedly, it selects the optimal multiplication order based on the matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to verify this kind of thing is to dump the lowered code via [`@code_lowered`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.@code_lowered) macro:

```
julia> @code_lowered A * B * x
CodeInfo(:(begin 
        nothing
        return (Core._apply)(Base.afoldl, (Core.tuple)(Base.*, (a * b) * c), xs)
    end))
```

Like many other languages, Julia does `y = (A*B)*x` instead of `y = A*(B*x)`, so it's up to you to explicitly use parens to reduce the allocation.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime $A * ($B * $x);
  6.800 μs (2 allocations: 1.75 KiB)

julia> @btime $A * $B * $x;
  45.453 μs (3 allocations: 79.08 KiB)
```